# Proving that a function is continuous in an interval

Tags: limits, continuity

I need to prove that $f(x)=x^2 \cdot \sin(\frac{1}{x})$ is continuous in $(0,\infty  )$.

---

My attempt:
Let $\varepsilon>0$. We define $\delta=\varepsilon$ and then for each $x,y\in(0,\infty)$, such that: $\left|x-y\right|<\delta$, therefore:
$$\left|f(x)-(y)\right|=\left|x^2\cdot \sin\bigg(\frac{1}{x}\bigg)-y^2\cdot \sin\bigg(\frac{1}{y}\bigg)\right|$$Since $\sin(x)<x$ then: $$\left|x^2\cdot \sin\bigg(\frac{1}{x}\bigg)-y^2\cdot \sin\bigg(\frac{1}{y}\bigg)\right|<\left|x^2\cdot \frac{1}{x}-y^2\cdot \frac{1}{y}\right|=\left|x-y\right|<\varepsilon$$

Did I got it right?

Comment: No, your inequality is wrong. Why don't you use theorems on continuity of products, compositions etc?

Comment: I can, but why my way isn't true?

Comment: It suffices to only show that $f$ is continuous at $0$, since this is the only problematic point. Simplifies the proof significantly.

Comment: $\sin x <x$ is true only if $x>0$.

Comment: @Bernard so can I divide it into cases?

Comment: Yes, but why do you want to prove continuity with the ε-δ definition?

Comment: @Bernard because if it was a test that is the first thing I would do. I am opened to see suggestions for solving this, but if you can show me in this way I will be glad.

Comment: @Bernard I hope you can show me the way I wanted to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would prove continuity as follows:

The function $f$ is continuous on $\mathbf R$, except possibly at $0$, as a product and composition of continuous functions.

We also see that $f$, which is defined on $\mathbf R^*$, has a continuous continuation at $0$, which means $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)$ exists.

Indeed,
$$|f(x)|=x^2\biggl|\sin\frac1x\biggr|\le x^2\cdot 1=x^2\to 0.$$

Comment: thank you a lot!